# Error witch 416 Status code when running a Node.js Discord bot on my computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I wrote a Discord bot that plays music when a condition is triggered. Hovewer, after a couple of minutes the song stops and I get the following error:

```
Error: input stream: Status code: 416
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (M:\ELTE\ZHbot\node_modules\miniget\dist\index.js:147:27)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:596:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
```

I'm rather new to Node.js/Discord.js
I tried to search for answers but only found that "The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 416 Range Not Satisfiable error response code".

I used the code found here as a template:
https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/dicord-music-bot

Code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const queue = new Map();

const prefix = '-';

const responseObject = {
    '<:gt:720365742733918300>':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qii15cvZX70',
    '<:no:719525207387275344>':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_LrHt4Hhhs',
    '<:isten:719523319933567006>':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psha3ecS5K8'

};


client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("Ready!");
});

client.once("reconnecting", () => {
  console.log("Reconnecting!");
});

client.once("disconnect", () => {
  console.log("Disconnect!");
});

var songInfo;

client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

    if(responseObject[message.content]){
            songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(responseObject[message.content]);
            execute(message, serverQueue);
    }else if (message.content === 'return 0') {
        stop(message, serverQueue);
        return;
  } 
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
  const args = message.content.split(" ");

  const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You need to be in a voice channel to play music!"
    );
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
  if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!"
    );
  }

  const song = {
    title: songInfo.title,
    url: songInfo.video_url
  };

  if (!serverQueue) {
    const queueContruct = {
      textChannel: message.channel,
      voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
      connection: null,
      songs: [],
      volume: 5,
      playing: true
    };

    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

    queueContruct.songs.push(song);

    try {
      var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
      queueContruct.connection = connection;
      play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      return message.channel.send(err);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    return "";
    //return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
  }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("There is no song that I could skip!");
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
      "You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!"
    );
  serverQueue.songs = [];
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }

  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
    .play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  //serverQueue.textChannel.send("#include \"library/buzibar.hpp\"");
  serverQueue.textChannel.send("#include \"library/" + song.title + ".hpp\"" + "\n" + "std::cout << \"Az embernek csak az arca ismerhető, de az arca nem ő. << std::endl; \nstd::cout << Ő az arca mögött van. Láthatatlan.\" (Gárdonyi Géza) << std::endl;\nreturn 0;"
  //,{tts: true}
  )
}

client.login('client-token');
```

Comment: Provide your Code. We cant help you without it.

Comment: Sorry, code added!

Answer (score 0):

so I'm having the same error on my project, I get it to happen when I send a message on my discord client while my bot is running but on a server that only runs my bot it will not give an error like this, the only solution to this I find is to move the bot somewhere that doesn't have a discord client, it could be a laptop or in my case a server that I run, it really doesn't matter where you decide to put it, Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting it on the same pc as your discord client listening sometimes the api gets confused and causes an error with the stream

Hope that fixes it - ItzWiresDev#6193

(DM me if that doesn't work)

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is happened when u write on your discord account and u start your bot on your pc.After i start my bot and write something is going to stop.